# Select jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that would let me do something similar to this in the image: 
[image]

Basically a user can chose one/more of the options like this. 
It looks like tags, but it's not really tag, and each element must carry it's ID too.

(in the future it should be possible to add options manually with ajax. but not necessary for now)

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI checkboxes should work for you:

http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, the checkboxes should do the trick for you.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

If you are not using either jQuery UI or Twitter bootstrap, you can implement this yourself with a small amount of CSS and minimal or no javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't really require jquery at all. You can just create form buttons and style them using CSS.

Comment: Hidden check-boxes to fulfill the "one/more" requirement.

Comment: ^ Yep, my bad. Checkboxes is probably the way to go.